# Adding to two tables, can't add foreign key to second table

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

So I have two tables, Employee and Login:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Employee] (
[EmpID]          INT           IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
[ManagerID]      INT           NULL,
[EmpName]        VARCHAR (50)  NOT NULL,
[EmpRank]        VARCHAR (50)  NOT NULL,
[EmpDateOfBirth] DATE          NOT NULL,
[EmpAddress]     VARCHAR (100) NOT NULL,
[DeptID]         INT           NOT NULL,
[EmpSalary]      INT           DEFAULT ((0)) NOT NULL,
[EmpGender]      VARCHAR (50)  NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([EmpID] ASC),
CONSTRAINT [FK_Employee_Department] FOREIGN KEY ([DeptID]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Department] ([DeptID])
```

and

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Login] (
[Username] VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
[Password] VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
[EmpID]    INT          NOT NULL IDENTITY,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Username] ASC),
CONSTRAINT [FK_Login_Employee] FOREIGN KEY ([EmpID]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Employee] ([EmpID])
```

So I have a page form to create a new Employee, which adds info to both the Employee and Login tables. With the Employee table this works fine, but with the Login table, I get an exception in Visual Studio as EmpID 'cannot be null', even though like in the Employee table it is also set to Identity. The exception occurs even if it's not set to Identity. So I'm wondering what I can do so that I can add a new Employee while keeping the same EmpID for the new record in both tables.

This is what the C# code to add the new info looks like:

```
SqlCommand sqlc = new SqlCommand("Insert into Employee(EmpName, EmpRank, EmpDateOfBirth, EmpGender, DeptID, EmpSalary, EmpAddress) values (@EmpName, @EmpRank, @EmpDateOfBirth, @EmpGender, @DeptID, @EmpSalary, @EmpAddress)", connect);
            sqlc.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmpName", TextBoxName.Text);
            sqlc.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmpRank", DropDownListRank.Text);
            sqlc.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmpDateOfBirth", TextBoxDateOfBirth.Text);
            sqlc.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmpGender", DropDownListGender.Text);
            sqlc.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DeptID", DropDownListDepartment.Text);
            sqlc.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmpSalary", TextBoxSalary.Text);
            sqlc.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmpAddress", TextBoxAddress.Text);
            SqlCommand sqlc2 = new SqlCommand("Insert into Login(Username, Password) values (@Username, @Password)", connect);
            sqlc2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", TextBoxUsername.Text);
            sqlc2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", TextBoxPassword.Text);

            connect.Open();
            sqlc.ExecuteNonQuery();
            sqlc2.ExecuteNonQuery();
            connect.Close();
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you `Login` table references the `Employee.EmpID`, then your `Login.EmpID` **CANNOT** be an `IDENTITY` column! You will need to manually **provide a valid value** for `EmpID` to the `Login` table that matches an `Employee.EmpID` !!

Comment: @marc_s is right. Better you should pick the EmpId of new employee created in Employee table and while adding details to Login table submit this value as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, the first thing to do is to remove the IDENTITY in the Login table EmpID.
This will be the same ID of the other Employee table, so you don't want the database to generate a possible different ID for the Login table.

Second, you need to retrieve from the Employee table the last id assigned automatically by the database.
This could be achieved appending the [SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190315.aspx) at the first query and retrieving the value assigned to the Employee identity column calling ExecuteScalar()

```
// Notice the semicolon at the end of the first query to separate
// the second command text. The result of this second command is returned 
// by ExecuteScalar
SqlCommand sqlc = new SqlCommand(@"Insert into Employee(EmpName, EmpRank, EmpDateOfBirth, 
                                   EmpGender, DeptID, EmpSalary, EmpAddress) 
                                   values (@EmpName, @EmpRank, @EmpDateOfBirth, 
                                   @EmpGender, @DeptID, @EmpSalary, @EmpAddress);
                                   SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()", connect);
sqlc.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmpName", TextBoxName.Text);
sqlc.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmpRank", DropDownListRank.Text);
sqlc.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmpDateOfBirth", TextBoxDateOfBirth.Text);
sqlc.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmpGender", DropDownListGender.Text);
sqlc.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DeptID", DropDownListDepartment.Text);
sqlc.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmpSalary", TextBoxSalary.Text);
sqlc.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmpAddress", TextBoxAddress.Text);
connect.Open();
int empid = Convert.ToInt32(sqlc.ExecuteScalar());

// Now pass the empid value to the second table 
// Remember to remove the IDENTITY flag from Login.EmpID otherwise
// you will get an error.
SqlCommand sqlc2 = new SqlCommand(@"Insert into Login(EmpID, Username, Password) 
                                   values (@empid, @Username, @Password)", connect);
sqlc2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@empid", empid);
sqlc2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", TextBoxUsername.Text);
sqlc2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", TextBoxPassword.Text);

sqlc2.ExecuteNonQuery();
connect.Close();
```

Comment: Thanks. I've removed the Identity flag from Login.EmpID. I can see what you mean by separating the commands for adding to the two tables and passing the EmpID from the first to the second. Unfortunately I'm now getting a "Incorrect syntax near ;" error message marking the ExecuteScalar statement.

Comment: Sorry, misplaced parenthesys. And changed the cast to a conversion because the object returned by ExecuteScalar cannot be cast to an integer, it needs a conversion

Comment: Thanks again, now though it's changed to a 'Specified cast is not valid' error.

Comment: It's working now! Thanks very much, I learned something today.

Comment: Yes, I was just updating the answer, glad to be of help